# PyGTK leave-notify-event shouldn't be triggered if enter children

Tags: python, pygtk

Please see this code example:

```
import gtk


class MenuBox(gtk.EventBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MenuBox, self).__init__()
        self.set_visible_window(False)
        self.connect('enter-notify-event', self._on_mouse_enter)
        self.connect('leave-notify-event', self._on_mouse_leave)

        btn = gtk.Button('x')
        btn.set_border_width(12)
        self.add(btn)

    def _on_mouse_enter(self, wid, event):
        print '_on_mouse_enter'

    def _on_mouse_leave(self, *args):
        print '_on_mouse_leave'


def main():
    win = gtk.Window()
    win.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
    win.add(MenuBox())
    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want that the enter and leave events are not triggered if I am going from parent to child and back. I know that in this particular case I can filter these events with `event.detail`. But this does not work if there is no border. If I remove the border the events aren't triggered at all.

In my real code I have a more complex widget (based on gtk.Fixed) which has border at the beginning but not at the end. So just moving the event to the child wouldn't do the trick either.

Answer (score 1):

```
#        self.set_visible_window(False)
        self.connect('enter-notify-event', self._on_mouse_enter)
        self.connect('leave-notify-event', self._on_mouse_leave)

        btn = gtk.Button('x')
#        btn.set_border_width(12)
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: From the point of functionality, yes. But I need the window of the EventBox to be invisible, too. Because I have a background image which would be covered by the EventBox window otherwise.