# gtk threads safety python

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, gtk, pygtk

I have a basic doubt about threads in gtk. I would like to run two functions in parallel in gtk . Is it ok if i use gobject_timeoutadd for the same .  if yes, should i use gtk.thread_enter and gtk.thread_leave ?

my idea of the program looks like this

```
import gtk,gobject

class Gtk_main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a=2
        self.b=3
        gobject.timeout_add(1000,self.test_1)
        gobject.timeout_add(1000,self.test_2)        


    def test_1(self):

        return True

    def test_2(self):

        return True



Gtk_main()
gobject.threads_init()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

This code is just an example. When i really used gtk.thread_enter and gtk.thread_leave, the program hangs. So i wanted to clear my understanding about gtk threads .

Thanks in Advance,
thothadri

Comment: I haven't looked so much on how one is supposed to do, but I've solved my threading in pygtk like the question here does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291055/pygtk-leave-notify-event-shouldnt-be-triggered-if-enter-children with the addition of the `threads_init()` like you allready have.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only timeouts, then you don't need to use GDK threads.

If you use both timeouts and threads, then you don't need to call `threads_enter()` and `threads_leave()` in your timeout callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your example hangs because `gtk.main()` calls `gdk_threads_leave()` before it enters the loop and `gdk_threads_enter()` after it exits the loop so if you call `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` your code should be something like the following one.

```
...
gobject.threads_init()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
Gtk_main()
gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
gtk.main()
gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
```

PS. I am not sure that `Gtk_main()` must go after thread initialization but I think it will not hurt.

As ptomato said, `timeout_add()` is not thread safe but this is a problem only if you need to call gtk functions from a different thread. A simple approach is:

```
import functools


def thread_safe(func):
    @functools.wraps
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwds)
        finally:
            gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
    return wrapper

threads_timeout_add = thread_safe(gobject.timeout_add)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Will try out and respond to you soon

Answer (score 0):

I always used Python and *not* GTK Threads in my programs, which worked well.

However, it's still necessary to `gobject.threads_init()` and maybe even `gtk.gdk.threads_init()`
depending on your GTK version.

Also you need to `import threading`, of which you'll find a superb documentation at the official python docs.